# Show values from MySQL Database on HTML page without PHP

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to web development. I have a HTML page with select dropdown and want to show some dynamic values to it from database and I am using Nodejs as server script. Is there any way I can achieve the same without using PHP? If yes, please share me sample code/link.

I tried generating page with dynamic values from server (used res.write) but I want to have static HTML page and perform operation.

```
res.write('<label style = "margin-left :5px"><b>LogFileName :</b> </label>');
res.write('<select name = "select1" id = "select1">');
res.write('<option hidden value="default" >Select file</option>');
for(var i in result)
  res.write('<option value='+ result[i].LogFile_Name + '>' + result[i].LogFile_Name +'</option>');         
res.write('</select>');
```

I want to have static HTML page and filled it dynamic values

Comment: You can create REST API and access that API using ajax and in success of that API you can create Dropdown

Comment: You can use node mysql driver to fetch data from database ([this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), for example).

Comment: you can google exactly the title of your question and get results that answer your question alredy. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Templating Engines ([ejs](https://ejs.co/), [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/), etc.).

**EJS SAMPLE**

*install ejs*

```
$ npm install ejs --save
```

*main.ejs*

```
<select>
  <option>Select file</option>

  <% resultData.forEach(function(result) { %>
    <option><%= result %></option>
  <% }); %>
</select>
```

*app.js*

```
var ejs = require('ejs'); 
var fs = require('fs'); 

var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/main.ejs', 'utf8'); 

var result = ['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3']; 

var renderedHtml = ejs.render(htmlContent, {filename: 'main.ejs', resultData: result}); 

console.log(renderedHtml);
```

Comment: Thanks,,It wortked for me

Comment: Can you suggest How to make one dropdown value to dependent on other with code?